# Packrat parser conflict

Tags: parsing, scala, grammar, context-free-grammar, shift-reduce-conflict

Suppose I try to parse a string *abc* with a Packrat Parser:

```
  lazy val abc: PackratParser[AnyRef] = ab ~ "c" 

  lazy val ab: PackratParser[AnyRef] = (ab | abc) ~ "b" | "a" 

  def parse(in: String) = parseAll(abc, in)
```

Here I use left recursion supported by Packrat parser, but I do not understand why it fails. According to Parser documentation P | Q equals P if P succeeds, so in this case `ab` should be replaced with "ab" instead of "a" as it does if I replace `ab` with:

```
  lazy val ab: PackratParser[AnyRef] = ab ~ "b" | "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

A Packrat parser supports left recursion, but does it support cycles between rules (without progress).

That's what you have here: abc calls ab which can call abc.

Maybe you should try putting the | in the abc rule to avoid the cycle.